# Rails assets without sprockets, SASS or LESS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I spawned my Rails site I removed Sass and I also removed sprockets.  I would like to spawn all my assets from app/assets/stylesheets and so forth but everything returns a 404.  How can I use `stylesheet_link_tag(:name)` without Sprockets or Sass-Rails installed so I can serve the raw CSS? Or is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your stylesheets in `public/stylesheets` and the asset pipeline will find them.

Comment: Or more correctly, use public/stylesheets when asset pipeline is disabled.